# How do I use boost.lambda with boost.range to select from a container?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, lambda

In C# with Linq, I would write:

```
myContainer.Select(o => o.myMember);
```

I'm not sure what the syntax should be for C++/lambda/range. I'm simply trying to adapt a container of some object type to a container of strings so that I can pass it to boost::algorithm::join. I tried something like:

```
using namespace boost::adaptors;
using namespace boost::lambda;
string result = join(myContainer | transformed(_1.myMember), ", ");
```

But obviously that doesn't work or I wouldn't be here. ;)

I'm using transformed after reading:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html

I want to use a lambda instead of a separate function for brevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator.` is not overloadable, thus it can never do anything sensible on a placeholder.

---

Boost.Lambda (and Boost.Phoenix v1 and v2, which were based on Boost.Lambda) implements its own result_of protocol rather than the TR1 result_of protocol, so Boost.Lambda functors will not work with anything using `boost::result_of` or `std::tr1::result_of` (as Boost.Range does).

That said, Boost.Phoenix v3, slated to be released in Boost 1.47, is the official replacement for Boost.Lambda and *does* implement the TR1 result_of protocol, and so does play nice with `boost::result_of` (and consequently Boost.Range).

Your options are to either use [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind/bind.html) instead of Boost.Lambda, in which case the following is valid:

```
transformed(bind(&myObjectType::myMember, _1))
```

or you can use Boost.Phoenix v3 instead of Boost.Lambda (either get Boost.Phoenix out of trunk now or wait for Boost 1.47), in which case the Boost.Bind syntax is valid, as well as the following alternative:

```
transformed(_1->*&myObjectType::myMember)
```

Comment: Very nice. But not compiling with boost 1.43 (using the lambda approach, not phoenix):
`boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp(43) : error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of 'boost::lambda::lambda_functor<T>'`

Comment: If it's expecting result_of why is it complaining about result_type? :/
`The BLL supports the standard library convention of declaring the return type of a function object with a member typedef named result_type in the function object class.`

Comment: @MattChambers : It's expecting the result_of _protocol_, which falls back on looking for a nested type `result_type` if no nested class template `result<>` exists; in this case, a nested class template `result<>` does exist but it is not specialized with the proper signature (IIRC). In any case, they're well-known to be incompatible, which is one of the primary reasons Phoenix v3 is officially superseding Boost.Lambda.

Comment: Ah, so the answer is that I can't and I should upgrade my Boost to use Phoenix. :) Thanks.